# If $ \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$ and $ \frac{a^3}{x}-\frac{b^3}{y}=b^2-a^2$, prove that $x^2-y^2=a^2-b^2$

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

The question, taken from a math book for competitions, goes as follows:

> Take the system $\displaystyle(\Sigma)=\begin{equation}
>     \begin{cases}
>       \displaystyle\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1\\
>       \displaystyle \frac{a^3}{x}-\frac{b^3}{y}=b^2-a^2
>     \end{cases}\,.
> \end{equation}$
>
> Prove that $x^2-y^2=a^2-b^2$

I tried to proceed by solving for $y$ in the first equation, like this: $\displaystyle y=\frac{b(a-x)}{a}$ and putting it in the second equation, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

The first equation is $xb+ya = ab$, while the second one is $a^3y - b^3x = xy(b^2-a^2).$
Let's rearrange the second one as $ay(a^2+ax) = bx(b^2+by).$ Using the first one, we get $a(a+x)(ab-xb) = b(b+y)(ab-ya)$. Thus, $(a+x)(a-x) = (b+y)(b-y)$, which implies the thesis.

Answer (score 2):

Luca's solution works, and is likely how they intended this to be solved. I'd like to point out that OP's approach of "substitute the first equation into the second" can be forced through to completion.

We have

- $ y = \frac{b(a-x)}{x}$ from the first equation, or $ bx+ay = ab$
- Substituting into the second equation and clearing denominators, we get $(a^2-b^2) x^2 + 2ab^2x - a^4 = 0 $.
- Similarly, $(b^2 -a^2) y^2 + 2ba^2y - b^4 = 0 $.
- Adding up these 2 equations gives us $(a^2 - b^2)(x^2 - y^2) + 2ab(bx+ay) - a^4 - b^4 = 0 $.
- Hence, $ (a^2 - b^2)(x^2 - y^2) = a^4  - 2ab(bx+ay) + b^4 = a^4 - 2a^2b^2 + b^4 = (a^2 - b^2) ^ 2$.
- Thus, if $ a^2 - b^2 \neq 0$, then $ a^2 - b^2 = x^2 - y^2$.
- If $ a^2 - b^2 = 0 $, then $ \frac{a^3}{x} \mp \frac{a^3}{y} = a^2 - a^2 = 0 $ so $ x = \pm y$. If so, $ x^2 - y^2 = 0 = a^2  - b^2$.

---

Alternative approach that still starts with the substitution, but is more algebraic manipulation intensive, though every step is pretty standard.

We have

- $y = \frac{b(a-x) } { x } $ from the first equation.
- Since $a, b, x , y$ are in the denominator, they are non-zero. In particular, $y \neq 0 \Rightarrow a -x  \neq 0 $.
- Substituting into the second equation, we get $ \frac{a^3}{x} - \frac{ab^2}{a-x} = b^2 - a^2$
- Multiplying throughout, $x(a-x)(b^2-a^2) = a^3(a-x) - ab^2x $ $\Rightarrow (a^2-b^2) x^2 + 2ab^2x - a^4 = 0 $.
- If $ a = \pm b$, then $ \frac{a^3}{x} \mp \frac{a^3}{y} = a^2 - a^2 = 0 $ so $ x = \pm y$. If so, $ x^2 - y^2 = 0 = a^2  - b^2$.
- If $ a \neq \pm b$, then $ a^2 - b^2 \neq 0$ and we can view this as a quadratic in $x$, which gives us the solution $ x = \frac{ - ab^2 \pm a\sqrt{a^4 - a^2b^2 + b^4  }} { (a^2 - b^2 ) }$.
- Similarly, we have the solution $ y = \frac{- ba^2 \pm b \sqrt{a^4 - a^2b^2 + b^4 } } { ( a^2 - b^2 ) } $. In particular, verify that they have the same $ \pm $ signage. (IE Given $a, b$, there are 2 solutions to the line cutting the hyperbola, and we've determined what they are.)
- In evaluating $ x^2 - y^2$, notice that when we square the numerators and subtract, then the cross terms cancel out. Hence,

$$ x^2 - y^2 = \frac{ (-ab^2)^2 + a^2(a^4 - a^2b^2 + b^4) + ( -ba^2)^2 + b^2(a^4 - a^2b^2 + b^4) } { (a^2 - b^2)^2 }     \\  = \frac{ ( a^2 - b^2)^3 } { (a^2 - b^2) ^2 } = a^2 - b^2.$$